# jBehave Tabular Parameter

Tags: java, bdd, browser-automation, jbehave

So I want to use the tabular parameter feature from jBehave, but from some reason **only the first column is taken into consideration**.

**Story**

```
Given I login using the users $userTable
|url    |userRole   |
|http://localhost:3000  |Administrator  |
|http://localhost:3000  |User   |
```

**Steps**

```
@Given("I login using the users $userTable")
public void givenUrlIsAccessedUsingTable
      (@Named("userTable")ExamplesTable userTable) {
List<Map<String, String>> rows = userTable.getRows();
for (Map<String, String> row : rows) {
    setupPreconditions(row.get("url"), row.get("userRole"));
}
```

[Actual result from report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLsjq.png)

The user column is not there.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the first ':' is missing symbol

```
 @Given("I login using the users: $userTable")
```

The second `Given I login using the users:` nothing here because the table under the statement is for that purpose

```
Given I login using the users:
|url    |userRole       |
|http://localhost:3000  |Administrator  |
|http://localhost:3000  |User           |
```

If you are using intellij idea  I suggest to use 
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7268-jbehave-support

for formatting

One more thing: naming for tha I suggest like  **Given users for logging:**

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I already have the plugin for intellij. Also I get the same result with your approach. But just one mention, if i leave out the userTable from the Given definition, then the IDE will not like it because the table is not recognized.

Comment: You could check the official guide for the syntax https://jbehave.org/reference/stable/tabular-parameters.html   I hope it can be helpful as well

Comment: Apparently something weird happens. I need to add the entire Given definition in the story, then remove the $userTable manually from the story. Thanks. It worked

Comment: By the way all the descriptions are space sensitive !